# Signup button not working in angular and not able to figure out how to connect frontend to backend

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, frontend, backend

I am new to angular so I am not able to figure out what's going wrong upon clicking signup button. Nothing is happing(not even throwing 404 or any kind of error). Also I am not able to connect angular to spring boot. Please help.

Code snippets are in below order.

1> Signup.component.html

2> Employee.service.ts

3> Signup.component.ts

4> EmployeeController.java

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card" style="width: 38rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="card-title text-primary">SignUp</h3>
      <hr>
      <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && addEmployee(f)" name="form" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text">  <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name"
                   name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" #nameTag="ngModel"
                   required [pattern]=unamePattern
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && name.invalid }">
            <div *ngIf="nameTag.touched && nameTag.invalid " class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="nameTag.errors && nameTag.errors.required"> name is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="nameTag.errors?.pattern">name is not valid</div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="email">  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"
                   name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" #emailTag="ngModel" required email [pattern]=emailPattern
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && email.invalid }" >
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && emailTag.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="emailTag.errors && emailTag.errors.required">Email is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="emailTag.errors?.pattern">Email must be a valid email address</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="phone">  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<!--            <input type="text" ng2TelInput (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)"-->
<!--                   [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry:'in'}"-->
<!--                   name="phoneCode" [(ngModel)]="employee.phoneCode" #phoneCode="ngModel" required>-->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone"
                   name="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" #phone="ngModel"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && phone.invalid }" required [pattern]=phonePattern >
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && phone.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="phone.errors && phone.errors.required">Phone Number is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="phone.errors?.pattern">Phone Number must be valid</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3 w-40">
          <span class="input-group-text" >  <i class="fa fa-male fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                  [(ngModel)]="empType" name="empType" id="empType" #empTypeTag="ngModel" >
            <option selected value="employee">Employee</option>
            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="admin">System admin</option>
          </select>
        </div>

<!--          <div  *ngIf="empType.value==='employee'" class="input-group mb-3 w-40">-->
<!--            <span class="input-group-text" >  <i class="fa fa-users fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>-->
<!--            <select  class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"-->
<!--                    [(ngModel)]="employee.manager" name="managerOfEmployee" id="managerOfEmployee" #managerOfEmployee="ngModel" >-->
<!--              <option *ngFor="let manager of managers" >{{manager}}</option>-->
<!--            </select>-->
<!--          </div>-->
        <div class="d-grid">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="showmodal">Loading-->
<!--</button>-->

<!--&lt;!&ndash; Modal &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">-->
<!--  <div class="modal-dialog">-->
<!--    <div class="modal-content">-->
<!--      <div class="modal-header">-->
<!--        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Please Wait</h5>-->
<!--        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>-->
<!--      </div>-->
<!--      <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center">-->
<!--        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>-->
<!--        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>-->
<!--      </div>-->
<!--      <div class="modal-footer">-->
<!--        <button type="button"  data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->

<!--      </div>-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--  </div>-->
<!--</div>-->
```

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Employee} from "../../shared/employee";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {EmployeeDto} from "../../shared/employeeDto";
import {ForgotPasswordDto} from "../../forgot-password/common/ForgotPasswordDto";
import {ResetPasswordDto} from "../../reset-password/ResetPasswordDto";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private apiServerUrl  =environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeeByEmail(email: string, password: string):Observable<Employee>{
    return this.http.get<Employee>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employees/${email}/${password}`);
  }


  getAllEmployeesUnderManager(name: string):Observable<EmployeeDto[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeDto[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/manager/${name}/employees`);
  }


  addNewEmployee( employee: EmployeeDto):Observable<Employee>{
    return this.http.post<Employee>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employees/addEmployee`,employee);
  }

  deleteEmployeeUnderManager(manager: number, employeeId:number) {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/manager/${manager}/employees/${employeeId}`);
  }


  getEmployeeUnderManager(manager: number, employeeId:number):Observable<Employee>{
    return this.http.get<Employee>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/manager/${manager}/employee/${employeeId}`)
  }

  updateEmployeeUnderManager(employeeId: number, employee: EmployeeDto):Observable<Employee>{
    return this.http.put<Employee>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employees/${employeeId}`,employee);
  }

  createEmployeeUnderManager(manager: number,employee: Employee):Observable<Employee>{

    return this.http.post<Employee>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/manager/${manager}/employees`,employee);
  }


  forgotPassword(body: ForgotPasswordDto){
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiServerUrl}/changePassword`,body);
  }

  resetPassword(body: ResetPasswordDto){
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiServerUrl}/resetPassword`,body);
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {Employee} from "../shared/employee";
import {EmployeeService} from "../services/data/employee.service";
import {EmployeeDto} from "../shared/employeeDto";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  managers =['balaji', 'ameen','abhiram']
  employee = new EmployeeDto(0,'','','',0,'');

  name :any
  email :any;
  empType:any;
  phoneNumber :any;


  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  unamePattern = '^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$';
  phonePattern = '[- +()0-9]{6,12}';
  emailPattern = '^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$';

  addEmployee(f:NgForm):void {

    console.log(f.value);

    this.employee.name = this.name;
    this.employee.email = this.email;
    this.employee.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber;
    this.employee.empType = this.empType;

    this.employeeService.addNewEmployee(this.employee).subscribe(
      response => {
        // if (!response) {
        //   this.showLoader();
        // }
        alert("Check Your Mail For Login Credentials");
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      },
      error => {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
      }
    )


  }

  initialCountry =  'in';

  onCountryChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.dialCode);

  }

  private showLoader() {
    document.getElementById("exampleModal");
    // @ts-ignore
    document.getElementById("showmodal").click();
  }
}
```

```js
@PostMapping("employees/addEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addNewEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDto employee) throws UserNotFoundException {
        if (employee.getEmpType().equals("employee")){
            return (employeeService.createNewUser(employee) != null) ?
                    new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED) :
                    new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

        }
        else if (employee.getEmpType().equals(EmpType.manager.toString())){
            if(managerService.createNewUser(employee) != null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
//        else if (employee.getEmpType().equals(EmpType.admin.toString())){
//            admin.createNewUser(employee);
//            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
//        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't post the controller code so I can't verify typo, but base on what I can
see here: usually when you not hitting the server the subscribe code is not
working properly.

I suggest you remove all these comments and error handling for a start and put
something like this:

```
this.employeeService.addNewEmployee(this.employee).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Also, have a look on the server log to find json parsing errors, this errors happened outsite the controller and can also be the reason you can't hit the controller.

Comment: Hey I have added the controller code, please check and guide. Thankyou.

Comment: what about the restcontroller base url

Comment: Hey here is the base url - 'http://localhost:8080/api'

Comment: from the controller you have something like @RequestMapping("/api") on top of the class?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: And you chnaged the angulsr service to the exmaple I sent? if that's the case follow these steps: 1. Put a consule message in the Angular service. 2. Match the emplyee from angular to the spring boot one, just remove all properties and leave id and name. 3. Add to your question the objects from both angular and spring boot so we can verify how you convert from json.